# How can I install a .patch for firefox in linux

Tags: linux, firefox, web

I have some problems with WebWorkers and crypto in mozilla firefox:
I've read that there is a patch here and i would like to try it

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=842818

the patch that i would like to try is:
0001-Bug-842818-Expose-WebCrypto-API-to-workers.patch
(https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8671339&action=edit)

its a patch. How can I install it?

I'm using Debian Jessie.

Comment: Download the Firefox source, apply the patch with something along the lines of `patch -Np1 -i /path/to/patch.patch` and then `make`, and `make install`. Keep in mind that you might also need to run a configure script and such. You should read the documentation before building anything from source. That being said,  the patch has probably been applied to the official version if Firefox, and downloading either an update or a new set of binaries should fix the problem. It all depends on how much you value this patch, and how much skill you have with compiling programs from source(if you wish to).

Answer (score 0):

You need to [download the entire Firefox code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Mercurial), apply the patch using the [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) program and then [build it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions).

I don't recommend doing it unless this is hugely important to you. The build step alone is [notorious](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984515) for only working on high-end PCs because of the memory requirements and even if it does work it will take forever.